# onreadystatechange function not being called in AJAX - PHP

Tags: php, ajax

This is my code. In this onreadystate function is not being called. Correct me if there are any issues in the below code

```
<!doctype html>
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';    
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    header("location:main_login.php");
    ?>

<html>
<head>

<script>
function show(){
    document.getElementById("cheque").value="";
}
function hide(){
    document.getElementById("cheque").value="Cash";
}
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.readyState;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_edit_payment.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
<form name="add_payment" method="post" action="add_payment.php">
<label for="select"><span style="text-align: center">Select Client:</span></label>
  <span style="text-align: center">
  <select name="client_name" id="select" onChange="showUser(this.value)";>
   <option value="">Select:</option>
   <?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM client");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"></div><br>
</html>
```

This code gives perfect output in some web pages and do not give any response in some. What could be the problem with this code

Comment: I don't see anything that calls `showUser()`.

Comment: I have added it now.Actually I missed out part of code

Comment: What you mean by " perfect output in some web pages and do not give any response in some. "  And, try to separate PHP. HTML & JS

Comment: Actually I have used this code from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp       When I copy code from that link, I am able to see output

Comment: AHA! Tipp: Never take code from examples.... those are just examples ;-) Do you understand, what the code does? Did you try something before coming in here?

Comment: Ya I understood it and implemented it in my web page. It also worked in one of pages in my application, and now I am using same thing in another page, it wont works now

Comment: I would like to know, is there any method to catch error,of why readystatechange is not called

Comment: Is the Path still correct, then? xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_edit_payment.php?q="+str,true);

Comment: `onreadystatechange` will always be called when the server replies to the AJAX call.

Comment: You have it!!! if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) .... else...

Comment: Are there spaces or other special characters in the `<option>` values? You should use `encodeURIComponent` when appending the value to the URL.

Comment: yes.. the path is correct

Comment: There are no special characters.. Only plane text in option values @Barmar

Comment: But is there any problem with the code?

Comment: Is the $_SESSION['myusername'] set?

Comment: What you mean by " perfect output in some web pages and do not give any response in some. " You have to tell us, where your problems are precisely. Sry, but I don't get your problem, try to show some error messages or edit your question

Comment: I have used similar code in another page, where I got response

Comment: What does the Network tab in Developer Tools say when the AJAX request is sent?

Comment: Nothing happens in network tab in developer tools, when I change values in drop down. No request is initialized

Comment: What could be the problem. Please help me .. am stuck

Comment: Did you try an absolute path for the file: ajax_edit_payment.php, like http://....

Comment: What values do have the xmlhttp.status and xmlhttp.readyState on failure?

Comment: I tried with absolute path. Still not working

Comment: how can I print xmlhttp.status and xmlhttp.readyState,if the onreadystatechange function is not called

Comment: Are you sure its not aborting on if (xmlhttp.readyState==

Comment: Ya... actually I have tried to print value of status and readyState, without using if condition. Even then I dont get response. So the problem is that onreadystatechange is not executed. What would be the reason of not being that function called

Answer (score 0):

You say, it gives sometimes perfect output and sometimes not: When using ajax, the browser may cache the results of the requested page (in this case `ajax_edit_payment.php?r=client`)

If you then had an error once, resulting in a empty page that call will always return an empty result, unless the browser cache is invalidated. When using ajax calls, it's a good idea to append a (timestamp-based) parameter to have an easy to implement, cross-browser compatible solution to enforce an invocation of the target script rather than using cached results:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_edit_payment.php?q="+str+"&r="+(new Date()).getTime(),true);
```

This will change the parameter "r" every second.

ps.: It might not be the solution for your problem, but "sometimes works and sometimes not" indicates a cache issue.